# Classical/ Quantum mechanical view of magnetic monopoles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, magnetic-monopoles

Is there any classical/ quantum mechanical proof for the non-existence of magnetic monopoles?
Or is it just lack of experimental evidence that has led us to the conclusion that monopoles do not exist, when in fact certain other theories predict their existence/ non-existence?

Comment: It is the lack of experimental evidences. And yes, some theories predicts their existence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#Grand_unified_theories_2

Comment: At least free magnetic monopoles http://news.sciencemag.org/2009/09/physicists-create-magnetic-monopoles-sort

Comment: @Lord_Gestalter I feel that this thing is mostly a case of condensed matter oversensationalization ;)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4784/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82745/2451 and links therein.